# Divide two Inputs and multiply 100

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have the two functions match and and total working properly. I want the function total project match to divide the first function over the second function multiply times 100. the last function isn't working!

Here is my code so far :

```
matchContribution.subscribe(function (newValue) {
          if (newValue != undefined && newValue != '') {
            matchContribution(formatInt(newValue));


        var dataValue = Number(matchContribution().replace(/\,/g, ''));

        if (dataValue > 999999999999.99 || dataValue < 0) {
          matchContribution('');
        }

        if (loading == false) {
          sendCommand('SAVE');
        }
      }

    });

    var totalProjectCost = ko.computed(function () {
      var total = 0;
      var hasUserInput = false;
      if (grantRequest() != '' && grantRequest() != undefined) {
        hasUserInput = true;
        total = total + Number(String(grantRequest()).replace(/\,/g, ''));
      }

      if (matchContribution() != '' && matchContribution() != undefined) {
        hasUserInput = true;
        total = total + Number(String(matchContribution()).replace(/\,/g, ''));
      }



      if (total == 0) {
        if (!hasUserInput)
          return '';
        else
          return formatInt('0');
      }
      else {
        if (loading == false) {
          sendCommand('SAVE');
        }
        return formatInt(total);
      }
    });

    var totalProjectMatch = matchContribution()/totalProjectCost();
    if(totalProjectMatch>=0)
      totalProjectMatch = Math.floor(totalProjectMatch);
    else
      totalProjectMatch = Math.ceil(totalProjectMatch);
```

Comment: Could you give more input about what the error is? And what exactly are you referring to? It is unclear what the second function in the posted code would be. And please add your question before posting any relevant code.

Comment: @SaschaM78, thank you for your response. I just want to divide the value of matchContribution  over the value of totalProjectCost and multiply by 100.  Thanks!

Comment: In the posted portion of code I can't see were you are multiplying by 100 (which would be `var totalProjectMatch = (matchContribution()/totalProjectCost()*100);` as you may most likely know). Have you tried getting the values of _matchContribution()_ and _totalProjectCost()_ using `console.log()`?

Comment: @SaschaM78 No I haven't. I just need help dividing matchContribution over
totalProjectCost times 100, Please!

Comment: This sounds a bit like basic math in JS. As I'm not a native english speaker I don't know what "dividing over" means, do you mean "divide matchContributon by totalProjectCosts multiplied by 100"?

Comment: @SaschaM78 Yes. Exactly. I'm not a native speaker either. I appreciate your help. I want matchContributon/totalProjectCosts times 100. Thank you very much!

Comment: In that case I would assume that it's `var totalProjectMatch = (matchContribution()/totalProjectCost()*100);` as mentioned earlier in the fifth lowest line of your code. Could you please check if that fits?

Comment: @SaschaM78, it didn't work. The output shows NaN :(

Comment: {I found the solution!}

`var totalProjectMatch = ko.computed(function () {
          var total = 0;
          var hasUserInput = false;
          if ((grantRequest() != '' && grantRequest() != undefined) && (matchContribution() != '' && matchContribution() != undefined) && (totalProjectCost() != '' && totalProjectCost() != undefined)) {
            hasUserInput = true;
            total = Number(String(matchContribution()).replace(/\,/g, '')) / Number(String(totalProjectCost()).replace(/\,/g, '')); 
            total = total * 100;
          }`

Comment: @TrEx You can post that as an answer.

Comment: @NisargShah Thanks! I just did.

Comment: Good you solved it but next time please try to be more precise with the actual problem. If you had posted the values of the two variables we could have seen that they had decimal and/or thousand separators which had made it easier to find the problem. Also please mark your own answer as solution so that the question does not maintain as open question.

Comment: @SaschaM78, Thank you! I will. Thanks again for your follow up!

Comment: Thanks for following my recommendation ;-). Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var totalProjectMatch = ko.computed(function () {
      var total = 0;
      var hasUserInput = false;
      if ((grantRequest() != '' && grantRequest() != undefined) && (matchContribution() != '' && matchContribution() != undefined) && (totalProjectCost() != '' && totalProjectCost() != undefined)) {
        hasUserInput = true;
        total = Number(String(matchContribution()).replace(/\,/g, '')) / Number(String(totalProjectCost()).replace(/\,/g, '')); 
        total = total * 100;
      }


      if (total == 0) {
        if (!hasUserInput)
          return '';
        else
          return formatInt('0');
      }
      else {
        if (loading == false) {
          sendCommand('SAVE');
        }
        return formatNumber(total);
      }
    });
```

I solved the problem! Thanks a lot! Hope that helps other people.